# Can i change alignment style of a particular column in asp grid that already has a default css style where columns where alligned left

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:GridView ID="Reports" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CssClass="datatable" EnableViewState ="true" llowPaging="True" AllowSorting="true" 
    CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" BorderWidth="0" GridLines="None" 
    SortedAscendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="sortasc" 
    SortedDescendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="sortdesc" SortedAscendingCellStyle-CssClass="sortasc"                 SortedDescendingCellStyle-CssClass="sortdesc" PageSize="10"                                                         onpageindexchanging="gvReports_PageIndexChanging">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change alignment of any TemplateColumn in asp.net grid. See following code for template column properties.

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Sr. No." ItemStyle-Width="4%" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"
    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="tablehead"> 
 <ItemTemplate>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Hope this will help..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can  change the style of on particular column in gridview, On row databound you can change the particular column style through css class or using style

```
protected void GrdView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

         if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
         {
           for (int i = 0; i > e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
           {
             e.Row.Cells[i].CssClass = "columnscss"; // using css class for each cell
           }
           GridView1.Columns[1].ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;// particular column
         }
}
```